# How to obtain a query string variable in PHP?

Tags: php, html

How can I get `id` of page?

I have list of 30 links, they look like:

```html
http://test.com/composition.php?=9
```

Here is my code:

```html
(index.php)
    <?
    $q = array();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $q[$row['id']]=$row['header'];

        }
    }
     ?>


 <?
       foreach($q as $href => $text) 
       {
           echo '<a href="http://test.com/composition.php?=' . $href . '">' .'<li>'. $text .'</li>' .'</a>';
       }

     ?>
```

How can i get `$href` at page `composition.php` when i click on link?

I tried `$_SESSION[href]=$href;`  - but it always shows me the last id of all links (=30) and i need that one i have clicked.

I'm sorry for noob question, I'm new to php and don't know hove to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<a href="http://test.com/composition.php?=' . $href . '">
```

to

```
<a href="http://test.com/composition.php?get=' . $href . '">
```

and on php file to get id

```
$id = $_GET['get'];
```

welcome

Comment: @GroD: be careful how you inject that value into a SQL query. Remember it can take any value, so it needs to be parameterised, escaped or cast (so people can't inject SQL of their choice into your query).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a key for the `$href` value so you can access it using the `$_GET` array:

```
foreach($q as $href => $text) {
   echo '<a href="http://test.com/composition.php?id=' . $href . '">' .'<li>'. $text .'</li>' .'</a>';
}
```

then in composition.php:

```
$href = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

the query values (values passed into a url following a `?`) are key-value pairs accessed using the `$_REQUEST` superglobal or the `$_GET` superglobal